# Suspending Web Request (Thread)

Tags: java, multithreading, request, suspend

I want to suspend the web request handler thread and  Another thread pool will handle the request concurrently and send response to client. Or thread pool send notification to the web request handler thread and this thread will send the response to client?

is it possible with Web Logic or another server like Tomcat?

Thanks
Trustin

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in how [Jetty does something like this with a form of continutations](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Continuations) -- testing has shown it can scale very well to many comet/ajax connections. However, this is Jetty-specific and may not be implementable using other stacks -- at least until the [Servlet 3.0](http://today.java.net/article/2008/10/08/introduction-servlet-30) spec is implemented (it introduces "suspendable" request).

YMMV. I don't actually touch Java web-stacks these days (thank goodness :-). Happy coding.

Comment: I have found the solution :)          // create ExecutorService to manage threads
        ExecutorService threadExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(N_THREAD);
        // start threads and place in runnable state
        try{
            for (int i=0; i<N_TASK;i++){
             PrintTask task = new PrintTask("thread" +i);
             tlist.add(task);
             Future f = threadExecutor.submit(task);
             futures.add(f);
            }
            for (int i=0; i<N_TASK;i++){
             futures.get(i).get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }            
        }

Comment: ExecutorService  and Future usage can help us :)

Comment: @Trustin25 Glad you found a solution. Futures are a nice generic approach to handle a number of join-able concurrency tasks. Just keep in mind that while the actions are run background threads, the primary request itself is still being blocked.